# how can others interact with my smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, dapps

How can I make my contract in a way that others can interact with it using metamask.
This is my code:
`dapp
let input = document.getElementById("myInput").value
contract.methods.create(input)
.send({from: "my address"})`

I want a way whereby whoever is interacting with the contract will have his/her metamask account address replace mine at the "my address" section.

Comment: You can probably just remove the `{ from: ... }` part and let the wallet fill that in. Not really sure though, since I don't use web3js much

Answer (score 0):

To create a dapp besides the usual technologies for web development you will need to communicate with the blockchain, for that you can use [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/) or [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/) libraries.